# quit application develop in flash release in Adobe air apk

Tags: flash, air, flash-cs5

i have develop one game in FLASH cs 5.5 and Action script 3.0 , my problem is i have put one close button in end of that game. but when i am press those button after make apk and test on mobile, it get no effect(means not quit my application).
thanks
nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickClose);
private function onClickClose(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
  NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}
```